# What's the status of my git submodule, and how can I clean it up?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-pull

Being a relative submodules noob, I wanted to update my submodule with from its origin, and did:

```
git pull
```

This resulted in:

```
remote: Counting objects: 111, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 57 (delta 54), reused 57 (delta 54)
Unpacking objects: 100% (57/57), done.
From github.com:eteanga/smarty
   8e9a011..818ab3e  master     -> origin/master
You are not currently on a branch, so I cannot use any
'branch.<branchname>.merge' in your configuration file.
Please specify which remote branch you want to use on the command
line and try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details.
```

Trying to fix:

```
git pull origin master
```

Output:

```
From github.com:eteanga/smarty
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 8e9a011..818ab3e
Fast-forward
[snip]
```

Now it seems that I did get the updated code, **but** I'm not currently working on any branch.

What should I have done to update my submodule correctly, and what should I do to fix this current state?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After a `git submodule update`, the `HEAD` in the submodule is set to the submodule commit-hash saved in the super project. If you want to reset the `HEAD` in the submodule to track the new commits in `origin/master` you first have to checkout to `master` and then to pull the changes:

In the submodule directory:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

Comment: Thanks kindly, that seems to have worked. Do I have to do this update on each machine that this main repo is checked out, to get them to pull the latest submodule code?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and it appears you have to do this for each submodule in each checked out repo. I'd like to find a solution where I can just clone my master repo using `git clone --recursive`, and then just push and pull changes for each submodule as needed. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: **Just hit me**: running both of the commands in the answer above after `git submodule foreach <command>` *seems* to do the trick. Uncertain of any potential side effects though...